# How to create new node programmatically, when a new user is created, in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, nodes

At the time when a new user is created, I want programmatically to create a new node (of some defined type) and make him the owner of that node.

How can I do this in Drupal 7 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct that you need to implement [hook_user_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7). The code that needs to be implemented is different from the code you would implement in Drupal 6 because the node body is a field, in Drupal 7 (see [Field API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/group/field/7)).

The implementation of `hook_user_insert()` should be similar to the following.

```
function mymodule_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $body_text = 'This is the text contained in the node body.'; // [1]
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'article';  // [1]
  node_object_prepare($node);

  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = $body_text;
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = text_summary($body_text);
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';

  $node->title    = 'Node Created Programmatically on ' . date('c'); // [1]
  $node->uid      = $account->uid;

  $path = 'content/programmatically_created_node_' . date('YmdHis'); // [1]
  $node->path = array('alias' => $path);

  node_save($node);
}
```

The lines marked with `[1]` are the parts that you need to personalize.

Answer (score 2):

This is done pretty much as Drupal 6. Create an object with the required values, and use `node_save`. This should all happen in `hook_user` op `insert`:

```
module_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->title = 'title'
  $node->uid = $account->uid;
  node_save($node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a new node inside an implementation of [hook_user_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7).